# Como verificar se uma checkbox está marcada e caso esteja, desmarca-la no Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Preciso realizar um teste no Selenium IDE com a seguinte situação

Possuo uma página onde existem 3 colunas com várias linhas ( Nome do campo, Status, Editável? )

No meu teste, preciso verificar se um determinado campo dessa lista está com a flag "Editável" marcada, e caso esteja, preciso desmarca-la para começar o teste

Exemplo: Meu campo se encontra na quinta linha dessa página, eu preciso varrer a lista ate encontra-lo e quando achar, verificar se essa check-box "Editável" está marcada, e caso esteja, desmarca-la.

Existe alguma maneira de verificar essa condição ?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que ficaria mais fácil se tivesse o trecho do código, mas vê se vc consegue entender:
Pega o elemento, e verifica se a propriedade `selected` dele está `true`. Se estiver, você dá um clique sobre ele.

```
elemQueVcQuer = browser.FindElement(By.XPath(".//tr[5]/input[3]");

if (elemQueVcQuer.Selected)
{
   elemQueVcQuer.Click();
}
```

Pelo que eu entendi você quer saber só como verificar se ele está ou não selecionado, né?
Se precisar como varrer a tabela, posta aí com o código, beleza?

Abraço